# Why lastfm api returns the wrong image?

Tags: api, last.fm

When I get track.search or user.getLovedTracks response, they have an image, but if I saw on any of the provided links then there will be a white image with a star, although if I go to my loved tracks page in lastfm the images will be correct.
For the example.
At lastfm:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKc5e.png
link to image: https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/64s/9c7a96efcdfa4e03cc8e1b65daac5281.jpg
At my service:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpIhj.png
link to image in request response: https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/64s/2a96cbd8b46e442fc41c2b86b821562f.png

The api returns a whole array of links to images, but they are all incorrect
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uiwrl.png

If you send a request with the track.getInfo method will response like:

```
{
    "track": {
        "name": "Без ключа",
        "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Pharaoh/_/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7+%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0",
        "duration": "159000",
        "streamable": {
            "#text": "0",
            "fulltrack": "0"
        },
        "listeners": "10491",
        "playcount": "78974",
        "artist": {
            "name": "Pharaoh",
            "mbid": "a6ed750a-7293-4e08-ba03-832373eb136b",
            "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Pharaoh"
        },
        "album": {
            "artist": "Pharaoh",
            "title": "Правило",
            "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Pharaoh/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE",
            "image": [{
                "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/6e92fe0cff920f671ee5eb4e2f0f4e59.png",
                "size": "small"
            }, {
                "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/64s/6e92fe0cff920f671ee5eb4e2f0f4e59.png",
                "size": "medium"
            }, {
                "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/174s/6e92fe0cff920f671ee5eb4e2f0f4e59.png",
                "size": "large"
            }, {
                "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/300x300/6e92fe0cff920f671ee5eb4e2f0f4e59.png",
                "size": "extralarge"
            }]
        },
        "toptags": {
            "tag": []
        }
    }
}
```

and the links in the album image will be correct

Comment: Probably a bug in the API. You could post that to the last.fm user group forum for help. But you could also help yourself to use `track.getInfo`.